# Select the earliest record in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Please consider the following table structure (this is sample data, so please ignore the timestamps being identical):

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| list_id | item_id | date_added | is_active |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
|    1    |     1   | 1352073600 |     1     |
|    1    |     2   | 1372073600 |     1     |
|    1    |     3   | 1332073600 |     1     |
|    1    |     4   | 1302073600 |     1     |
|    2    |     1   | 1302073600 |     1     |
|    3    |     1   | 1302073600 |     1     |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Our client wishes to show how many lists were created on a certain day. The list is created when the first item is added, but the date is not explicitly stored, only the date the items have been added.

My question is this:

Using MySQL (and PHP for computing the timestamp), how can I return the number of lists that were created on a certain day. Essentially, the logic should be (pseudo-code):

- select total records from `tbl_list_items` where `date_added` >= min_age and `date_added` <= max_age, and record is oldest for this list

It is difficult to explain what I'm looking for, so consider the following actions:

```
No items added to lists yet (i.e. all lists have 0 items)
User added `item_id = 1` to `list_id = 1` yesterday.
User added `item_id = 2` to `list_id = 1` today.
User added `item_id = 1` to `list_id = 2` yesterday.
User added `item_id = 1` to `list_id = 3` yesterday.
User added `item_id = 2` to `list_id = 2` today.
```

If we wanted to look how many lists were created yesterday (or rather, how many lists had the first item added yesterday), I would like to return the total number where the item first added = yesterday. Given the action set above, this would return a total of 3 (i.e. `list_id = 1`, `list_id = 2` and `list_id = 3`).

Comment: what will be your desired output?

Comment: So, date_added, what does it represent exactly in that table, is it the list_id or item_id date?

Comment: So this means that an item X can be added today, to a list Y created yesterday ? In this case, looking for "today", the list Y should count or not ?

Comment: @Andrea, the list is created only when an item is added. Therefore, it can be inferred that the earliest addition to list Y was the creation date for that list.

Comment: Yes, that's clear to me, but my question is a bit different. Let's imagine that at day #1 we add an item to list Y (so we create the list); at day #2 we add another item to list Y (so we only "update" the list); so list is created on day #1 and if you query for day #1 you should find list Y. My question is: if you query for day #2, list Y (created on day #1 but updated on day #2) should be found or not ?

Comment: @Andrea, sorry for the confusion. No, it should not be included. Only lists which had the first item added on the day we're querying. I've updated my question to include a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the list of lists created on a specific day:

```
SELECT list_id, min(date_added) AS date_creation
FROM tbl_list_items
GROUP BY list_id
HAVING min(date_added) >= @min_age AND min(date_added) <= @max_age
```

To count them you can count number of results of the query, or use sub-queries like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM
(
    SELECT list_id, min(date_added) AS date_creation
    FROM tbl_list_items
    GROUP BY list_id
    HAVING min(date_added) >= @min_age AND min(date_added) <= @max_age
)
```

However, note that this is totally not-optimized, because you have to GROUP BY the whole table for each query; maybe will be better to add a flag ( creation = 0 | 1 ) when the first item of a list is added.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to adapt your query to do what I needed. Now to get the client to optimize the DB ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_list_items WHERE date_added >= :min_age and date_added <= :max_age GROUP BY date_added
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have multiple tables to normalise your data.  One for list, and another for list item.

**Table List**

ListID

ListCreatedDate

...any other list information...

**Table ListItem**

ListID

ListItemID

ListItemCreatedDate

...any other list item information...

This way you'll have access to the list creation date as well as individual item dates.  Then you can simply join on List.ListID = ListItem.ListID to get all of your information.

Comment: I know about normalization (have worked with DBs > 10 years), but the db was not designed by us, and for legacy reasons the structure of the db and table relationships cannot be changed.

Comment: @JohnWoo I have edited my question to indicate my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like unix timestamps, in which case you could do something like

```
SELECT ..
FROM ...
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_added)) = '2012-11-03'
```

Note that this will be inefficient, since you're comparing derived values - indexes won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select records from one particular day, why would you specify `min_age` and `max_age`? You just need to compare to a single date (say, of the format YYYY-MM-DD):

`select count(*) from table_name where from_unixtime(date_added, %Y-%m-%d) = $date group by list_id`

or something like that.